# Move to already allocated view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ad the title says, I'm wondering how I move back to a already allocated view. In this case I have three views, `Mainmenu`, `Main_game_view` and `game_over_view`. I want to move back from game_over_view to mainmenu without reallocating it. Also note that I'm using xib files

How do I do that?

Comment: It depends on how you went forward. If you went forward with modal presentations, then you go back by dismissing. If you went forward with pushes, then you go back with pops. In either case, it will take you back to the same instance of MainView that you started with.

Comment: Add some code and process that you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use storyboard, you can create a segue by control-dragging.

If you move from viewController1 to viewController2 by `[viewController1 presentViewController:viewController2 animated:YES completion:nil];`, you can use `[viewController2 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` to go from viewController2 back to viewController1.

If you use a `UINavigationController` and push viewController2 by `[someNavigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];`, then you can do `[someNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` to pop the view controller and go back to the first view.

If it's multiple views presented on the same view controller, then you can remove the views from their super view using `[someView removeFromSuperview]` and leave the first view only.

Hope it helps :)

========

Edit:

You can create a reference of your `Mainmenu` in your `Game_over_view` view controller:

1. In `Main_game_scene` view controller's .h file, create `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *mainMenuViewController;`. After `Mainmenu` creates `Main_game_scene` view controller, do `main_game_scene.mainMenuViewController = self;`.
2. In `Game_over_view` view controller's .h file, also create `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *mainMenuViewController;`. After `Main_game_scene` creates `Game_over_view`, do `game_over_view.mainMenuViewController = self.mainMenuViewController;`.
3. Now you have a reference of `Mainmenu` in `Game_over_view`, just call `[self.mainMenuViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`.

Comment: thank you! But how do i do it if i want to move from Game_over_scene back to main menu? I mean if i do [Game_over_view dissmissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] it will just go back to the main_game_scene instead of the main menu? how do i fix that? I'm using presentViewcontroller to present my view.

Comment: @user3534757 You can create a reference of your `Mainmenu` in your `Game_over_view` view controller, and do something like `[self.mainMenuViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`. I edited my answer with the steps. :)